# How to stitch multiple images that are in a random order using OpenCV in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

Using OpenCV in python, I am trying to stitch multiple images that are out of order. I have a functioning stitch method that stitches two images, given which one is on the left and right.

```
    def stitch(self, images, ratio=0.75, reprojThresh=4.0, 
    showMatches=False):

    """
    This function performs image stitching with help of other member functions of Stitcher class.
    Args:
        images          (list)  :   List of two images ordered left to right 
        ratio           (float) :   Ratio for Lowe's Test
        reprojThresh    (float) :   reprojThresh parameter for RANSAC for homography computation
        showMatches     (bool)  :   Flag for marking showing matches on input images
    """

    (imageL, imageR) = images

    #Find key points and features for input images
    (kpsR, featuresR) = self.find_kp_features(imageR)
    (kpsL, featuresL) = self.find_kp_features(imageL)

    # Match features between two input images
    M = self.matchKeypoints(kpsR, kpsL, featuresR, featuresL, ratio, reprojThresh)

    if M is None:
        return None


    (matches, H, status) = M
    #Perform perspective correction on second image (imageR)
    result = cv2.warpPerspective(imageR, H, (imageR.shape[1] + imageL.shape[1], imageR.shape[0]))

    #Insert Left image (imageL) in result to obtai stitched image
    result[0:imageL.shape[0], 0:imageL.shape[1]] = imageL

    if showMatches:
        vis = self.drawMatches(imageR, imageL, kpsR, kpsL, matches,
            status)

        return (result, vis)

    return result
```

source: https://github.com/TejasBob/Panorama/blob/master/image-stitching-report.pdf

I have read through the following [paper](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcvgl.stanford.edu%2Fteaching%2Fcs231a_winter1415%2Fprev%2Fprojects%2FChau_Karol_CS231a_Final_Paper.pdf), but I am still confused on an approach to stitching multiple images together that are in a **random order**. I have considered using a bundle adjustment algorithm,  but am unaware of a possible implementation for this.

My question is what would be the best way to stitch together multiple images that are out of order? Some suitable material or pseudo code of what I can do will also be helpful.

Comment: What do yo mean by *'I fixed it'*? Can you share your approach?

Comment: Sorry, that was a response to the moderator's comment. I have not found a solution yet. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: [THIS BLOG](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/) can help you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple images stitching available in random order you can try the following:

1)find feature in one image

2)try to match those features in all the images

3) the image for which you get maximum match with initial image select that and perform the stitching

4) now you have a new stitched image, and you can features in it and match them again in other frames and so on.

It would be time consuming but something in this direction can be thought.

Comment: Thanks, but could you possibly provide a snippet of code for this procedure?